# What's wrong??? it's only seven lines

Tags: c++, namespaces, cout

this may be a duplicate and I'm sorry if it is. I'm new to C++, as in a few hours new, but why won't my code work? it returns that there is unexpected-id before "{" and that cout is undefined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main();
{
    cout<<"hi";
    return 0
}
```

I've tried ending with "<< endl" after the string and adding a semicolon after 0.
I'm using CB13.12 if that helps at all and yes I am using C++ and not C.

Comment: You put a semicolon in a function header. Leave it as int main(). 

Also you DO need the semicolon after return 0.

Comment: You should really invest in a C++ book and not try to guess how to write a C++ program.  Every C++ book that I know of starts off with the simple C++ "Hello World" program where the include is `<iostream>`

Answer (score 4):

`#include <iostream>` instead of `<stdio.h>` and remove the semicolon after `main` (`int main();`) /thread

Comment: The OP *may* need to output a `\n` or use `std::endl` in order to flush the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Typos and missing proper header file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"hi";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TeddyT Don't give up after only a few hours ;-) C++ requires many many hours before you truly master it....

Answer (score 0):

delete the semicolon after `main()` and also use `<iostream>` not `<stdio.h>`